# Search all words in Meilisearch / Laravel Scout

Tags: laravel, search, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I'm using Laravel Scout with Meilisearch for typeahead searching of a list of titles. I am also using it to match duplicates with different spellings. The issue I have is that Meilisearch brings up results that match any word. For example typing `the world` brings up:

```
The First Result
The Second Result
The World
World, The
World Games
World Test
```

When I need it to match both worlds and only return `the world` and `World, The`. Is there a way to achieve this with Meilisearch?

Answer (score 1):

MeiliSearch sorts documents by decreasing number of matching query terms: https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/core_concepts/relevancy.html#ranking-rules

You could perform a [phrase search](https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/features/search_parameters.html#phrase-search) but it will only return documents containing those terms **in the order they were given**.

So I am afraid it's not possible to achieve that ATM, but there is a card that the public roadmap which seems to fit your needs, it would be great if you could upvote it: https://roadmap.meilisearch.com/c/62-policy-for-matching-words